# Get event ID of Google Calendar event after it has been created C#

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I've written some code to add an event to Google Calander:

```
                    var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    new ClientSecrets
                    {
                        ClientId = "ID",
                        ClientSecret = "Secret",
                    },
                    new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar },
                    Account.Text,
                    CancellationToken.None).Result;

                    var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
                    {
                        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                        ApplicationName = "Custom CRM",
                    });
                    var myEvent = new Event
                    {
                        Summary = Title.Text,
                        Location = AppointmentLocation.Text,
                        ColorId = Convert.ToString(AppointmentColourInt),
                        Description = Description.Text,

                        Start = new EventDateTime()
                        {
                            DateTime = new DateTime(StartDate.Value.Year, StartDate.Value.Month, StartDate.Value.Day, Convert.ToInt32(StartTime.Text.Substring(0, 2)), Convert.ToInt32(StartTime.Text.Substring(StartTime.Text.Length - 2)), 00),
                            TimeZone = "Europe/London"
                        },
                        End = new EventDateTime()
                        {
                            DateTime = new DateTime(EndDate.Value.Year, EndDate.Value.Month, EndDate.Value.Day, Convert.ToInt32(EndTime.Text.Substring(0, 2)), Convert.ToInt32(EndTime.Text.Substring(EndTime.Text.Length - 2)), 00),
                            TimeZone = "Europe/London"
                        },
                    };

                    var recurringEvent = service.Events.Insert(myEvent, CalendarID);
                    recurringEvent.SendNotifications = true;
                    recurringEvent.Execute();
```

Is there a way I could get the ID of the event once it has been created so that I can save it to my database for future reference?

Thanks.

Comment: recurringEvent.Id? https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/recurringevents#.net

Answer (score 2):

```
var recurringEvent = service.Events.Insert(myEvent, CalendarID);
recurringEvent.SendNotifications = true;
var results = recurringEvent.Execute();
```

Execute will return to you the object it inserted.  The Id should be in there.